# How does Blood Star work?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Succubi in Acts III and IV have energy orbs they toss your way that give you the debuff "Blood Star."

Blood Star states:

> A curse that reduces Monk and Barbarian Armor by 50%, and causes Wizard, Witch Doctor, and Demon Hunter skills to do casting cost as damage back to the caster.

[image: Blood Star]

As a wizard, I've noticed that I take roughly **1k damage** when this is active and I'm channeling Disintegrate. I'm *pretty sure* that Disintegrate doesn't cost 1k Arcane Power, so - how does Blood Star work? Does the damage change by difficulty? Does my armor reduce the damage? Which resist affects Blood Star damage?

Comment: Didn't notice on NM, this Hell and up?

Comment: @NickT I know I noticed it in Hell, and I haven't gotten anywhere near there in Inferno. I do know I don't remember having to worry about it in Normal/NM, then was surprised at the threat it provided in Hell.

Comment: I have gotten this curse in Normal. I barely noticed the damage it was doing; I assume it is scaled up in Nightmare/Hell/Inferno, but perhaps the tooltip doesn't reflect this.

Comment: This was the bane of my existence in Nightmare.  I think my Rapid Fire DH died more from this one debuff then everything else in NM combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue when channeling Rapid Fire as a Demon Hunter. There seems to be two things in play here:

- It deals its damage *per hit*. For channeled spells, this is extremely fast.
- It scales up for harder difficulties. 20 damage per hit on Inferno would mean nothing. (sorry, no exact numbers)

This curse is applicable at all levels, it's in game from Normal onwards. The simplest way I found to deal with it is either:

1. Don't get hit by it. The balls they fire are very slow moving and turn very slowly. This usually makes them fairly easy to dodge. If you have it, Teleport should make this trivial.
2. If you do get hit, **avoid channeled spells**. They will kill you very quickly. Any other types of spell seem to do minimal damage in Normal and Nightmare (I haven't played Act 3 past there personally).

With respect to your last two questions about armor/resists, it's hard to tell at this point in time. There's very little information available about enemy abilities like this, and the lack of a combat log of any type makes it difficult to determine damage types. From my personal experience I don't think that using armor/resists to mitigate the damage coming from channeling is the way to go, just because of the sheer volume of damage that is done.

**Blood Star related bug fixes in patch 1.0.3**

*[Link to 1.0.3 Patch Notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/Patch_103_Now_Available-6_19_2012#blog)*.

- The Succubus "Blood Star" debuff will no longer affect the player if the damage from the projectile is dodged/blocked/etc
- The damage from the Succubus “Blood Star” debuff will now scale based on the current cost of a player's skill, even if the cost is reduced by items or skill runes

Answer (score -1):

It is based on the cost, but is multiplied by a large amount on inferno.

Also remember that it takes into account your armor, resistances and any damage reduction skills you may have.

Comment: You have a source to support that?

Comment: @JamesJiao Is there any type of damage which *doesn't*?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Confused. Doesn't what?

Comment: @JamesJiao doesn't take into account your armor, resistances, or and damage reduction skills. That was what you were contesting, yes? That it *does* ignore those things?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Fair enough. But how does one know that? That's why asked the question. I never said his answer's wrong. Intuitively, he might be right. By the way, I wasn't the one who voted this down.

Answer (score -1):

im a dh and blood star curse was my most feared.....i'd die fast..it seems to reflec damage back at me if i fire especially rapid fire.....i tried not firing while under the spell and found that my life didnt go down at all.....so my advise is...1 dodge them, but if you get hit....keep running /dodging till curse up.....this hjas worked for me...im lvl 60 and play inferno mp4...hope this makes sense )