# List of Act 4 Curse (Debuff) Effects and Visuals

Tags: diablo-iii

What are all the curses, which can be cast on a player in Act 4? I've seen little graphical buff icons appear in Hell Act 4, showing "Curse of Mud" I think, amongst others. I have been unable to find a list of these effects or the graphical effects on the player character, which each produces.

I am aware of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66116/what-are-the-special-abilities-the-unique-champion-monsters-can-have) answer, which is not related.

Comment: This is going to turn into a rather large list, and there's not really any benefit to it; debuffs don't last long enough to be a threat, and if they are, you die, and they fall off.

Comment: @fbueckert In hardcore, learning that something is a threat by dying is not the preferable way to go.

Comment: I don't know if the list is really that big.  I'm only aware of a few special debuffs in the game, though bloodstar (the succubus one) is by far the most dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

There's a list of five Curses/debuffs in [this forum thread](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8198730793):

- Curse of Anguish:  "You take more damage from attacks.  All healing and health regeneration effects are reduced."
- Curse of Rust:  "Armor reduced by 50%"
- Curse of Weakness:  "All outgoing damage is reduced by 25%"
- Terrorized:  "Healing reduced by 75%"
- Curse of Resistance:  "All resistances reduced by 50%"
- [Curse of Hatred](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8198730793#10):  "You take more damage from attack, but also inflict more damage with your attacks."
- [Curse of Mud](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/7618102193):  movement debuff.
- [Blood Star](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71291/how-does-blood-star-work):  "A curse that reduces Monk and Barbarian Armor by 50%, and causes Wizard, Witch Doctor, and Demon Hunter skills to do casting cost as damage back to the caster."

That's eight total (five from the original list plus three others).